# jQuery .on() not firing event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-1.7, jquery-on

#### Scenario

I have a list of users, within each list item is a `<header>` and a `<div>` wrapper - they are siblings:

```
<li class="user">
    <header>
        // ...
    </header>
    <div class="user-wrapper">
        // ...
    </div>
</li>
```

I am toggling the `div` wrapper when the user `header` is clicked.

#### What currently works:

```
// the handler is called
$('li.user > header').live('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.user-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

As `live()` has been deprecated and *I am* using jQuery 1.7.2, I want to use `on()`.

#### What does not work:

```
// Direct style
$('li.user > header').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.user-wrapper').toggle();
});

// Delegated style
$('li.user').on('click', 'header', function () {
    $(this).next('.user-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

In either `on()` scenario, the anonymous handler function is not being called.

#### Question

First... why is `on()` choking?

Second... if/when it works, using the delegate style, can i still reference the header's sibling div in the same manner as above?

Comment: Are the `li.user` elements dynamic as well? In that case you have to select an ancestor for `.on`: `$('ancestor').on('click', 'li.user > header', ...)`.

Comment: Both work here http://jsfiddle.net/meVe4/2/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I found it. It has to do with knockout. The LI items look static, but I think with one particular binding they are being treated different. I'll post my conclusion here shortly. @thecodeparadox helped me put together a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [EDITED]

For delegate event handling the syntax of **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** is:

```
// 'element' must be static and an ancestor to 'target'.
$(element).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction);
```

Your delegate scenario above should work, assuming your `li.user` tags are static at the time of binding.

```
$('li.user').on('click', 'header', function () {
    $(this).next('.user-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

If you test this in jsFiddle, it works as is. It seems like your `li.user` elements are being created dynamically.

If `li.user` is dynamically created then use a different (static) parent selector. If your list `ul` is always present, for example:

```
// HTML
<ul class="user-list">
  <li class="user">
    <header>
        // ...
    </header>
    <div class="user-wrapper">
        // ...
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

// JavaScript
$('ul.user-list').on('click', 'li.user > header', function() {
  $(this).next('.user-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Right. It's common to use the `document` object, e.g. `$(document).on('click','myselector',function(){});`

Comment: @GriffeyDog if we know about any static parent element of target, then using `document` as container should avoid.

Comment: Agreed, use the most specific static container you can.

Comment: @thecodeparadox your code and mine are entirely the same... both `on()` scenarios I listed are NOT firing the `function()` handler. Am I blind to something?

Comment: @thecodeparadox my understanding is that "direct style" places the handler on all headers directly under the list item, where the "delegate style" places a single handler on the list item itself, and waits for click events on the header children to bubble up. Both syntaxes in my example should work, no?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer `delegate event` handler will bind event to all element that are still present in DOM at page load and will come to DOM in future(dynamically).

Comment: @thecodeparadox - `jabbr.net` is back up `/join jquery`. i'll be here for a bit.

Comment: @thecodeparadox thank you for talking with me. it turns out knockout.js was being used to template the `li` tags from a json collection. The first time the collection reloaded, the .on() bindings broke.

Answer (score 0):

#### Thanks

Lots of gratitude to **@thecodeparadox** - his answer explains the issue best and is marked as such.  My answer below just explains the details of how/why the list items became dynamic.

#### Further explanation

`Knockout.js` is being used to template the `li` elements. This alone was not the issue as the `li` elements were created before the `.on()` bindings occurred and are still treated as "static".

The killer was a `ko.computed()` property on the knockout model. The property reloads the collection here/there. From the moment the collection is reloaded, the scaffolding of the `li` items is redone and all the `.on()` break.